# EF TPT Inheritance - mapping 1-M related table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Hi I am using TPT inheritance in EF. I have BaseClass=AspNetUser. SubClasses =Employer and Employee. I want to add a Document class which has a 1-M relationship with AspNetUser, so that you can only see your own documents. When I try to add a document from the Employer screen for example, i want to add an item  to the Employer Documents Collection. It is not adding a record to the database though. What is the correct way to add an item to this collection. Do you have to navigate to the base class? 
I want to be able to do something like this

```
var avatar = new Document {...}               
employer.Documents = new List<Document> { avatar };
db.Entry(employer).State = EntityState.Modified;
db.SaveChanges();
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First in the `AspNetUser` class, initialize the collection `Documents` in the constructor like code below. If you're using Database First approach then this already be done by the EDMX:

```
public AspNetUser() 
{
    this.Documents = new List<Documents>();
}
```

Second, to add a new document in your `Documents` collection just do this:

```
var avatar = new Document {...}               
employer.Documents.Add(avatar);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Make sure that you retrieve your `Employee` instance from your `DbContext`.